# Division Between Buffers in Node.js using 1024bit values

Tags: node.js

In a nodejs application I have these 1024bit-sized buffers:

```
const buf1014_1= Buffer.alloc(1024,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45, 16);

const buf1014_2= Buffer.alloc(1024,0xFFFFFFFF1234FFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFF12334FFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFF332FFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45FFFCD123FFFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAADDDAF2345FF45, 16);
```

And Somehow  I cant to calculate the values generated by dividing `buf1014_1` with `buf1014_2`

In other words I cant to calculate `buf1014_1 / buf1014_2`. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: JavaScript only has 64bit numbers. And because it implements IEEE 754, only integer values up to 53 bits are precise.

Comment: So I need somehow to split them and calculate byte per byte... Hmm perhaps some C++ may help here....

Comment: Actually what I try is to calculate Burmester Desmedt: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/54020/42421